# How use parameters in Loop Activity in IBM Datastage?

Tags: mysql, parameters, datastage

I'm in this situation: i have a table of certain data with month associate.
I want load another table with the data of current month and the previous 'n'(i want to insert n).

For example: We are in July(7) and insert 3 as 'n' . the job must be load July-June and May.
It's possible set in Loop activity these parameters? 
Such as: FROM:  , STEP:-1 , TO:  - n (but this form doesn't work)

Or there are other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A loop is not necessary at all - from what I understand - you want to dynamically select the time range from one table to write it to anotherone. The probably easiest way is to  use a flexible WHERE Conditrion in the SELECT statement. The WHERE condition or parts of it can be a parameter. 
An example could be:

```
SELECT <whatevercolumns>
FROM <sourcetable>
WHERE date > month(current date) - #NumMonths# months
```

alternatively

```
SELECT <whatevercolumns>
FROM <sourcetable>
#WHERE#
```

And you specify the whole WHERE condition in the parameter.